# OutPut the values of a program

Tags: java, output

Here is have a program that will output the following:
3
6
3
6
7
The program is this:

```
public class test3 {
static int x=3;
public static void main(String args[]){
    test3 t = new test3();
    System.out.println(x);
    int x=6;
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(t.x);
    t.xupdate (x);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(t.x);
}
public void xupdate(int y){
    x=7;
}
}
```

Why is the last value the program outputted 7? I thought it would be 6.Please someone explain this messed up code to me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the static variable of class `test3` to 7, in the following two statements which are after `t.xupdate(x);` the first outputs the local variable value which is 6 and the second outputs the static class variable which was set to 7

```
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(t.x);
```

You needed to change `xupdate` to set `x=y` if you expected the last value to be 6

Answer (score 1):

You have updated the value of `static variable x` inside the method, so you're getting 7 instead of 6. See the below code for clear understanding

```
public class test3 {
    static int x=3;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        test3 t = new test3();
        System.out.println(x); //prints the value of static variable x which is outside main method
        int x=6;
        System.out.println(x); //prints the value of variable x initialized inside main method
        System.out.println(t.x); //prints the value of static variable outside the main method
        t.xupdate (x); //Passed the value 6 to the method, but you changed the static variable inside the method to 7. So the current value of variable x outside the main method is 7
        System.out.println(x); //prints the value of static variable inside the main method
        System.out.println(t.x); //prints the value of static variable outside the main method
    }
    public void xupdate(int y){
        x=7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void xupdate(int y){
    y=7;
}
```

You changed the static variable x. Typo?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void xupdate(int y){
    x=7;
}
```

should be

```
public void xupdate(int y){
    x=y;
}
```

what's the role of y otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Line 't.xupdate(x)' calls method 'xupdate(int y)' where you assign 7 to x. In this method you use instance variable x declared in 2nd line refred from main method as 't.x' not local variable x.

Reading about scope of variable would help you understand it.